# Actionbarsherlock back button doesn't go back

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

When I press the home button it doesn't go back like I think it would do.

```
public class TotalOverview extends SherlockActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);  

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

I also tried catching it with this method

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    boolean toReturn = false;
    int id = item.getItemId();  
    if( id == R.id.abs__home)
    {
        toReturn = true;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

but that didn't work I did get into this method but the id is not the same id
as the R.id.abs__home. So how can I get this to work.

The emulator I am using has android version 2.3.1. For the rest everything from the 
actionbarsherlock works like expected.

The blue block is the button I click, and with clicking that I want to navigate back.
[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `android.R.id.home` to detect the home affordance, not `R.id.abs__home`. For example, from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite/T12-Book), using ABS 4.0.2:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        pager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
        return(true);

    // more code here for other cases
  }
```

Comment: okay I get it now, now I only have to send it to the previous action. So thanks.

Comment: The important point was to use android.R.id.home. I tried it only with R.id.home and relied on the generated R instead of Androids R. Thanks for the clarifications :)

Answer (score 1):

it's bug and it's was reported here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/dsZr7z4_xvU